# Crystal Report 13.0.2 giving "Load Report Failed" on web server for some reports while other are working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have crystal report 13 in my application. Its working fine on local server but giving Load report failed error on web server. Here is exception details-

```
     Message: Load report failed.
     Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  
     Source: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine 
     StackTrace: at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
          at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ProductLocaleID()
          at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.CachedObjectReportSource.GetReport(RequestContext context, Boolean bAddToCacheWhenCreated)
          at CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportSource.get_ReportDocument()
          at ABC.AB.ABReportCardCrystal.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    InnerException: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
          at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
          at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
          at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
```

I have tried registry edit, temp permission, resource release but its not working. Is there any other reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. but For anyone still looking for the answer:

Did you register Crystal Reports in page markup?

```
<% @ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

Set the property 'Copy to Output Directory' of the report to 'Copy always'

The path of the file in the crystalreportsource will be ~/bin/YOURFOLDER/YOURFILE

```
<CR: CrystalReportSource ID ="CrystalReportSource1" runat ="server">
            <Report FileName="~/bin/FolderName/ReportName.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR: CrystalReportSource>
```

Try this and see if it works for you.